# Creating UIView through protocol

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, swift-protocols

Yesterday I was reading about Protocols, and how to powerful they're. One of the answers was here in Stack Overflow saying:

"You can think of protocol if you said *a class **has a** feature*, and a superclass when you say *my child class **is a** thing*"

So, in my situations, I have 3 `UIViewControllers`, each has a `UIPickerView`. Thus, I thought of making a `protocol` that adds a `UIPickerView` for conformed classes of type `UIViewController`.

I have created a playground just to test working with `UIView` throughout protocols.

My issues were:

a) Couldn't create UIViews with code, so I created a function to create UIViews.
b) Couldn't add constraints because the views are inside the function.

It's worked fine before I set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false. But I need to add constraints by myself.

Finally, **my questions is:**
I want to reach to point where a `UIViewController` just conform to a protocol and **has a** `UIView` implemented in it without adding extra code to it. How is that possible? and if not, what is the best thing to do to reach to what I'm looking for.

I have created the following playground for tests:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

protocol Labelable {
    func label() -> UILabel
}

extension Labelable where Self: UIViewController {
    func label() -> UILabel {
        let helloLabel = UILabel()
        helloLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 20)
        helloLabel.text = "Hello World!"
        helloLabel.textColor = .black
        //helloLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //helloLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        //helloLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        //helloLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        //helloLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        return helloLabel
    }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, Labelable {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let lab = label()
        view.addSubview(lab)

        self.view = view
    }
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MyViewController())
```

*Note that uncommenting the constraints lines makes a huge number of calls to the protocol method.*

Comment: Based on the example code I doubt that you've quite understood the way protocols are intended to be used. Protocol extensions should be used scarcely and should definitely not be used to create UIViews. For that purpose you'd better use inheritance. There are many other scenarios where protocols can be quite handy though.

Comment: I do use protocols in many handy ways. What I'm trying to do here is applying the "Has a" and "Is a". So in my case, I have a custom superclass for the `UIViewController`. not all its subclasses will have a `UIPickerView`, thus, I thought about protocols to add a functionality to some of the subclasses. Few of them will have a `UIPickerView` presented in custom animations, etc. Adding this functionality by just conforming to a protocol will be very helpful.